# connection rejected by remote interface error after upgrade to firebird 2.5.0

Tags: .net, mono, centos, firebird

I use  Mono 2.6.7, CENTOS, Firebird AMD64 2.1.3 and FirebirdSQL Provider 2.5.2, all worked fine, but when firebird dataserver was upgraded to 2.5.0 version, i get this error message:

```
"Unable to complete network request to host "No message for error code 335544721 found."
```

also, I get this one sometimes:

```
"connection rejected by remote interface"
```

My connectionstring on appsetting

```
<add key="conns"  Value="database=/home/db.fdb;user=sysdba;password=masterkey;datasource=localhost;charset=ISO8859_1;"/>
```

I have tried change datasource to localhost, 127.0.0.1 and servername, nothing works, also i changed charset to NONE, not work too. After I upgrade to 2.6.5 provider version, but i got the same error too.

Server is running, in fact, I can connect to firebird server from IBExpert fine remotely.

Something curious: I can load the webapplication only first time, but when I reload the page, I get the error messages

Comment: Shoudn't user=sysdba be uppercase? (...;user=SYSDBA;password=masterkey...)

Comment: @Duilio The username in FB is **not** case sensitive; password is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve the same isue just to delete the localhost attachment to the database, for example i put in my connectio string localhost:c:\data\mydb.ib, and replace it with c:\data\mydb.ib and all work just fine.